# Кулдаун на команды

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Хочу сделать кулдаун на команды, но чтобы при этом бот работал дальше
Примерное использование:
Я: !команда
Бот: выполняет команду
Я: !команда
Бот: Вы сможете использовать эту команду вновь через 3 мин. 23 сек.
Как то можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для такой задачи отлично подходит [Redis](https://redis.io/) или [Memcached](https://memcached.org/).

Но в качестве примера я покажу на обычном словаре.

Делаем декоратор который будет вызывать наш хендлер если `interval` уже прошел, иначе вызывать `rollback`.

```
In [123]: import time

In [124]: import functools

In [125]: aka_redis = {}

In [126]: def countdown(interval, rollback):
     ...:     def wrapper(func):
     ...:         @functools.wraps(func)
     ...:         def inner(message, *args, **kwargs):
     ...:             user_id = message.from_user.id
     ...:             if user_id not in aka_redis:
     ...:                 aka_redis[user_id] = time.time()
     ...:             else:
     ...:                 ttl = time.time() - aka_redis[user_id]
     ...:                 if ttl < interval:
     ...:                     return rollback(message, interval - ttl)
     ...:                 aka_redis[user_id] = time.time()
     ...:             return func(message, *args, **kwargs)
     ...:         return inner
     ...:     return wrapper
     ...:
```

Теперь создадим наш роллбэк:

```
In [127]: def rollback(message, ttl):
     ...:     print(f"User: {message.from_user.id} can retry in {ttl}.")
     ...:
```

И наконец сам хендлер:

```
In [128]: @countdown(5, rollback)
     ...: def handler(message):
     ...:     print(f"Hello, {message.from_user.id}!")
     ...:
```

Проверяем:

```
In [129]: handler(message)
Hello, 1337!

In [130]: handler(message)
User: 1337 can retry in 3.7606029510498047.

In [131]: handler(message)
User: 1337 can retry in 2.7380571365356445.

In [132]: handler(message)
User: 1337 can retry in 1.0794241428375244.

In [133]: handler(message)
Hello, 1337!
```

Конвертировать секунды в более читаемый вид:

```
In [134]: from datetime import timedelta

In [135]: timedelta(seconds=500)
Out[135]: datetime.timedelta(seconds=500)

In [136]: str(_)
Out[136]: '0:08:20'
```